# Numbering in the Mordechai

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, commentaries

I've noticed that the Mordechai has a strange numbering system (א,ב,ג etc.) that goes through it. I thought it might just be enumerating the individual halachos l'maaseh, but I noticed that it often appears mid-phrase in the Mordechai, suggesting that it's not just a numbering system. I looked around for something that it might be referencing, like another commentary, but it doesn't seem to point anywhere specific. For example, you can see the numbering in the first paragraph here going from עג to עח:

[image: Mordechai]

Where are numbers these pointing to? What does it represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great question, as it exposes the problem with the Mordechai, one of the thorniest medieval texts in terms of the significantly different versions and abridgments produced over the generations, which make an authoritative version of this thirteenth-century compilation of Ashkenazic laws and customs quite challenging.

The numbering system you refer to developed out of Italian editions produced in the mid-16th century that included the Rif, Mordechai, and Tosefa in one book. **R. Yehoshua Boaz**, a Spanish exile who moved to Italy and wrote the commentary to the Mordechai called *Shiltei Hagibborim*, numbered the Mordechai in order to make the work an accessible companion to the laws of the Rif. Later editions of the Mordechai and the Rif corrupted this numbering system, exacerbated by the loss of a work Boaz made of this numbering system.

This information is based on the wonderful research of Avraham Halperin. He explains the complicated textual history of the Mordechai and its commentaries in the Machon Yerushalmi edition of the Mordechai, a revised, critical edition that relies on several archived manuscripts. It is there, in the introductory volume (pp. 37-38), that he writes the following paragraphs (with my quick translation of the relevant information):

> לא עברו אלא כשלשים שנה מעת הדפסת הרי"ף, עם המרדכי והתוספתא בוונציה
> כנ"ל והנה התחילו בעת ובעונה אחת שני בתי דפוס באיטליה להכין מהדורא חדשה
> מהם. בית הדפוס האחד הוא של הנוצרי אלויזי בראגאדין בוונציה, והשני - של
> המדפיס היהודי טוביה פואה בסביוניטה בדפוס בראגאדין הופיע הספר בשנת שי"ב
> (1552) ובסביוניטה - בשנים שי"ד-שי"ט  (1554-1559). הטכסט בשניהם - גם של
> הרי"ף, גם של המרדכי וגם של התוספתא  - מועתק מדפוס וונציה ואף סדר הדפים
> והעמודים בהם הוא כמותו (ורק לעתים יש הבדל קל ביניהם, המתבטא בהעברת
> שורה אחת או שתיים מסופו של עמוד אחד אל ראשיתו של משנהו). בשניהם הופיע
> הספר בשלשה חלקים. החידוש המיוחד שהוכנס בהם הוא כפול: ציון ההלכות - גם
> ברי"ף וגם במרדכי - באותיות לפי סדר הא"ב והוספת פירוש בשם ״שלטי
> הגבורים״ אף הוא בשניהם. ההלכות צויינו על ידי הדפסת מעגל קטן ליד מילת
> המפתח בפנים והאות בשוליים בצד. בכל אחד משלשת החלקים ערוכים סימני
> האותיות בסדר שוטף מתחילה. סידור זה, וכן הפירוש הנ"ל הם פרי עבודתו של
> רבי יהושע בועז, בעל התורה אור, העין משפט והנר מצוה שעל הגמרא. בהקדמתו
> למהדורא זו (והיא העתקה לרוב המהדורות הבאות של הרי"ף ונמצאת גם אתו בראש
> הרי"ף למסכת ברכות שבדפוסי הש"ס דירן) כותב יהושע בועז, שהוא מיין וריכז
> את כל הדינים שבתלמוד בשני חלקים: ״עצות בנפשי שמתי לתת בסדר על ספר
> תמי"ם כל הדינים הפשוטים בלי מחלוקת וגמגומים וכל הדינים אשר בהן מחלוקת
> להציגן כסדרן על ספר המחלו״קת״. וכוונתו היתה כדבריו שם: ״לערוך שלחן מכל
> הפוסקים אשר מתוך התלמוד הוציאו פסקים צדיקים, וסביב לו איש על מקומו
> באותות אמרתי להקים, ואזי בשטיטת עין אחת ימצא איה איפה בספר דבריהם
> חקוקים״. מפרי עבודתו (אולי כהכנה לספרים המתוכננים הללו) נתברכנו במראי
> מקום כל דין שעליו פסק האלפסי ברב חילו, איפא (!) הביאו אותו בחבורים
> מיימון וסמ"ג (ספר מצוות גדול) וטור באותות גדול על דגלו, כפי סדר שכתבתי
> למעלה סביבו כתבתיהו, ולו שם עין משפט קראתיהו, גם לכל דין אות מאלפא
> ביתא למנין שם חקקתיהו, לנר כל מצוה שם הצגתיהו. אולם הקובץ המרוכז של כל
> ההלכות הללו במסגרת ״ספר חקר דינים״ של התלמוד, המבטח לנו בהמשך דבריו שם
> לא הגיע  לידינו
>
> לעומת זאת, מעבודת הסימון המקבילה שנעשתה על ידו לרי"ף ולמרדכי (כדבריו שם: ״ועשיתיו לקצות פסקי הרי"ף הנ"ל סמני חקר דינין וסדרתיהו להלכותיו וכן ספר האשר"י ז"ל סדרתי סי' כל פסק דין שלו בדגלו לאותותיו וכן קיצור ספר מרדכי סדרתיהו להלכות בסימניו עם הגהותיו״)  נדפסו
> בשתי המהדורות הללו בראגאדין וסביוניטה לוחות הדינים לשניהם
>
> הלוחות לספר המרדכי יצאו גם אחר כך בהוצאה נפרדת בשם ״קיצור מרדכי
> וסימניו״. בדפוס וויצנטו קונסי בקרימונה, בשנת שי"ז (1557). ואמנם חלוקת
> סימני הדינים שבלוחות אלה לפני אותיותיהם מתאימה בדיוק לסימנים שליד
> הטכסט ברי"ף ובמרדכי
>
> הדפוסים המאוחרים נהגו בתחילה להעתיק על פי מהדורה זו את סימני האותיות
> בשולי הטכסט (ולא תמיד הדפיסו את לוחות חיקור הדינים) ואחר כך - בתוך
> הטכסט עצמו (כגון בדפוס ווארשה תרי"ט-תרכ"א, למברג שעם הש"ס תר"ך-תרכ"ה
> ובדפוסי ווילנא-ראם המאוחרים). כיון שסימני האותיות הללו נסובים רק על
> ההלכות המצויות והמפוזרות בטכסט הרי שאין כל קשר ביניהם לבין חלוקתו של
> הטכסט לפיסקאות או לסעיפים. קורה להן, שבפיסקה מסויימת יש כמה סימני
> אותיות וכנגדה, בפיסקה אחרת שאין בה הלכה התואמת את המובא ברמב"ם, אין כל
> ציון. כמו כן באים כרגיל סימני האותיות הנ"ל ליד מילות המפתח ולאו דווקא
> בראשי הפיסקאות שם. בגלל חוסר חלוקה מגדרת של הטכסט גם ברי"ף וגם במרדכי
> השתרש הנוהג לציין את המקומות בשניהם לפי סימני אותיות אלה לראות בהם
> מעין ציוני סעיפים, למרות שאין הם עונים כלל וכלל על כך
>
> Not thirty years since the Rif was printed alongside the Mordechai and
> the Tosefta in Venice, as mentioned above, that two printing houses in
> Italy began to make a new edition of them at the same time. The first
> printing house was by the Christian, Alvise Bragadin in Venice, and the
> other by the Jewish printer Tuvia Foa in Sabbioneta, the book appeared
> in the Bragadin printing press in 1552 and in Sabbioneta in the years
> 1554-1559.
>
> The text in both editions - each with the Rif, the
> Mordechai and the Tosefta - was copied from Venice, and even the order
> of the pages is the same (and only sometimes there is a slight
> difference between them, which is expressed by moving one or two lines
> from the end of one page to the beginning of another). In both
> editions, the book appeared in three parts. The special innovation
> introduced in them is twofold: **the marking of the laws - both in the
> Rif and in Mordechai - in letters according to the order of the
> alphabet** and the addition of a commentary with the name "Shiltei
> Hagibborim" in both.
>
> The laws were indicated by printing a small
> circle next to the keyword on the inside and the letter on the side
> margins. In each of the three parts the letter marks are arranged in a
> starting order. **This arrangement, as well as the aforementioned
> commentary, are the fruit of the work of Rabbi Yehoshua Boaz**, the
> author of "HaTorah Or", the "Ein Mishpat" and the "Ner Mitzva" on the
> Gemara. In his introduction to this edition (and it is a copy of most
> subsequent editions of the Rif and it is also at the
> beginning of the Rif on Tractate Brakhot in the printed editions of
> Shas), Yehoshua Boaz writes that he sorted and summarized all the laws
> in the Talmud ...However, the abridged compilation of all these laws in
> the "Sefer Heqer Dinim" of the Talmud, assures us later in his remarks
> there, that these works have been lost.
>
> Nevertheless, from the parallel numbering work done by Boaz for the Rif
> and the Mordechai ... in both of these editions, Bragadin and Sabbioneta
> printed the lists of laws for each of them.
>
> ...Indeed, the division of the laws in these lists are according to
> letters that correspond exactly to the signs next to the text in the
> Rif and in the Mordechai.
>
> **Subsequent editions started copying this edition, incorporating the
> alphabetically ordered arrangement on the margins of the text (and did
> not always print the lists of the laws) and later - within the text
> itself (such as in the Warsaw and Vilna editions). Since these letter
> marks revolve only on laws found and scattered throughout the text,
> there is no connection between them and the division of the text's
> paragraphs or sections. Sometimes a certain paragraph  will have
> several letter marks and, by contrast, another paragraph that has no
> laws corresponding to what is presented in the Rambam, doesn't have
> any.**
>
> **Likewise, the aforementioned letter marks appear next to keywords and
> not necessarily at the beginning of the paragraphs there.** Due to the
> lack of a defined division in both the texts of the Rif and the
> Mordechai, it has become customary to indicate the places in both
> according to the lettered numbers to see as kinds of section markers,
> even though they do not correspond with each other.